# Stop current Thread and then create a new thread that performs the same operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, runnable

My problem is that I cannot figure out a way of having a thread that "on the click of a button starts, and stops on the click of another button", and then if I click the same start button a NEW thread starts that does exactly the same operation as the first. So basically just a new instance.

In my program I have a Server app that has 2 buttons and 2 text fields. After the user has entered the correct username and password the Server app opens a new ServerSocket that listens for clients that want to connect. This is done in a separate Thread to prevent the GUI from freezing. After the stop button is pressed the Thread is stopped.

How can I get my program to start a new Thread, that does the same as the first one, when I press the start button again in the GUI? Must I perhaps make use of a loop?

Server App Code:

```
public class Server extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel instructionsLabel;
    JLabel passwordLabel;
    JPasswordField passwordTF;
    JButton shutdownButton;
    JButton startupButton;
    JLabel usernameLabel;
    JTextField usernameTF;
    Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ServerRunnable());

    public Server() {
        super("Server");
        initComponents();
    }
                               // My problem is here
    public void starterMeth() {
        MyThread.start();
    }

    public void stopMeth() {
        MyThread.interrupt();
    }
                                // in these 2 methods
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        String f = "n";
        ConnectionBean cb = new ConnectionBean();

        char[] a = passwordTF.getPassword();
        String b = new String(a);
        String inputDetails = usernameTF.getText() + b;

        Iterator it = cb.getDetails().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object next = it.next();
            if (inputDetails.equals(next)) {
                f = "y";
                if (source == startupButton) {
                    if (!MyThread.isInterrupted()) {
                        starterMeth();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Congratulations! Server started.",
                            "Start-up Message",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please restart the server application.",
                            "Start-up Message",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else if (source == shutdownButton) {
                    stopMeth();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Server shut-down successfully!",
                        "Shut-down Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                // only resets the text fields when the correct details are entered
                passwordTF.setText("");
                usernameTF.setText("");
            }
        }
        if (f.equals("n")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username or password.", "Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        cb.setCloseConnection(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
    }
}
```

My Runnable Code:

```
public class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);

            while(true) {
                Socket cs = ss.accept();
                new ClientThread(cs).start();
        }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview**

Although the creation of a `thread` is valid in Java, it is highly discouraged for numerous reasons. The most significant one is that the creation of a `thread` is quite costly and resource intensive. In addition, there are much safer/efficient models implemented in the standard library that could be used to simplify the issue. In this particular scenario, I would advise against this implementation because of the nature of the operation; *start-stop reoccurring*. Note, a `thread` cannot be restarted once it has been *started* and the only way to stop a thread while executing is to call `interrupt()`. Unfortunately, interrupting a thread requires the developer to implement error handling in the `run()` method. Below we will see the `run()` method of a `Runnable` or a `Thread` implementation.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // Your connection logic would be here
        yourLogic();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Maintain status
    }
}
```

Lets assume you made your own `thread` implementation called `MyThreadImpl`. Below we will see how to utilize it:

```
public void starterMeth() {
    Thread myThread = new MyThreadImpl(); // Create thread
    myThread.start(); // Start execution in parallel
}

public void stopMeth() {
    myThread.interrupt(); // Stop the thread
}
```

Alternatively if you implement your own `Runnable` like you are in this application, it would look like this:

```
public void starterMeth() {
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ServerRunnable()); // Create thread
    myThread.start(); // Start execution in parallel
}

public void stopMeth() {
    myThread.interrupt(); // Stop the thread
}
```

*Although both of theses are valid, there are better approaches.*

**A better approach**

My suggestion is to utilize the [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class due to its robust implementation and desirable control. CompletableFutures utilize the global `ForkJoinPool.common()` for its threading so that the application can execute with more efficiency. In addition, you can receive the [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html) that is within the object for later use instead of attempting to re-create it each time. Lets investigate how this implementation would work below:

```
public class Server {
    CompletableFuture<Void> myFuture;
    ...

    public void starterMeth() {
        myFuture = new CompletableFuture<Void>(); // Create future
        myFuture.runAsync(new ServerRunnable()); // Start execution in parallel
    }

    public void stopMeth() {
        myFuture.cancel(true); // Stop the future
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java ***does not allow*** to restart a Thread once it has ***finished executing***.

Interrupting the Thread you created will simply finish its execution. The problem here is that you are using the same Thread that has finished executing (once the stop button has been clicked).

I suggest one of the following:

1. Improve your runnable so that when the user attempts to clicks the ***shutdownButton*** button, it stops what it was doing, and acquires some sort of semaphore to make it "sleep" until the ***startupButton*** is hit again.
2. (Easier) Always create a new thread on ***starterMeth***. Don't forget to check if a Thread is running and interrupt it before starting a new thread.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So I should create a new thread like this every time I call "starterMeth()"......

      public void starterMeth() {
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ServerRunnable()).start();
    }

Comment: Exactly, that way it's always a new thread that is on a _not executed_ state.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I get the concept now, but one thing that still escapes me is how would I stop this thread?

Comment: The same way you do on **_stopMeth_** by calling the interrupt, and closing the ServerSocket that you created in the thread. Note that just interrupting the Thread won't be enough, you've gotta close the ServerSocket manually because of the **_accept_** method that blocks until a new connection arrives at your ServerSocket. You can achieve this by maintaining a reference to the ServerSocket that your thread constructs (so you can access it to close it manually). Closing it will throw a SocketException (IOException), you can choose to discard it if you're interrupting the thread by force.